# Context wrapper openOrclosedatbase exception in Android?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am creating an application in which I need to use broadcast Receiver, My issue is, I can't pass Broadcast.this as database context.

I tried to create another activity and used Activity.this in database context but no use.

Please can anybody let me know how to use database context in Broadcast receiver.

My broadcast receiver is like here:

```
 public class BroadCastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
String[] Doc_Id;
FolderList DocListId;
DMS_Database database;
Context context;
final public static String ONE_TIME = "onetime";
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{   
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    Toast.makeText(context, " Alarm Received !!! ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    database = new DMS_Database(context);
    List<FolderList> DocList = database.getAllDoc();
    database.close();
    System.out.println(DocList.size());
    for(int i=0;i<DocList.size();i++)
    {
    DocListId = DocList.get(i);
    Doc_Id = new String[DocList.size()];
    Doc_Id[0] = DocListId.getId();
    Intent Idintent = new Intent();
    Idintent.putExtra("doc_id", Doc_Id[0]);
    System.out.println(Doc_Id[0]);
    Update up = new Update();
    up.Updatefile(Doc_Id[0]);
    }
}
public void CancelAlarm(Context context)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, BroadCastReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(sender);
}
public void onLogin(Context context){

}
public void SaveAlarm(Context context)
{
    AlarmManager alarms = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, BroadCastReceiver.class);
//  intent.putExtra(ONE_TIME, Boolean.FALSE);
    PendingIntent recurringDownload = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
            0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    alarms.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),
            1000 * 10, recurringDownload);  
}
 //Tried to make another Activity in same Broadcast receiver, to use database context but o use
public class Update extends Activity
{   
    String ID;
    String fileLongName;
    String UserFileName;
    String url;
    String fileExtension;
    String lastModifiedDate;
    String SubjectType;
    boolean IsUpdated;
    DMS_Database db;
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    private static final String URL = "http://192.168.1.5/InterLogicsMobile/InterLogics.asmx";
    private static final String UPDATE_FILE_METHOD = "GetDocumentUpdatedInfo";
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION_UPDATE_FILE = "http://tempuri.org/GetDocumentUpdatedInfo";

public void Updatefile(String Doc_Id)
{
    try
    {
        SoapObject Subfolderrequest = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, UPDATE_FILE_METHOD);
        Subfolderrequest.addProperty("DocumentID", Doc_Id);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(Subfolderrequest);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION_UPDATE_FILE , envelope);
        SoapObject DocResponse = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();    
        Log.i("Uspdated Documents", DocResponse.toString());    
        for(int i=0; i < DocResponse.getPropertyCount(); i++)
        {
            SoapObject SingleSubFolder = (SoapObject)DocResponse.getProperty(i);        
            ID = SingleSubFolder.getProperty(0).toString();
            fileLongName = SingleSubFolder.getProperty(1).toString();
            UserFileName = SingleSubFolder.getProperty(2).toString();
            url = SingleSubFolder.getProperty(3).toString();
            fileExtension = SingleSubFolder.getProperty(4).toString();
            lastModifiedDate = SingleSubFolder.getProperty(5).toString();
            SubjectType = SingleSubFolder.getProperty(6).toString();
            IsUpdated = SingleSubFolder.hasProperty("IsUpdated");
            if(IsUpdated==true){
            db = new DMS_Database(Update.this);
            db.update_Doc(ID, UserFileName, url);  
 //Gettig error here & in database update_Doc method...
            db.close();
    }
}   
    catch(Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, " Network Exception : " + e
                + "Please check network connectivity.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [context.getApplicationContext()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationContext%28%29), also you should do it on new thread.

Comment: I am using single application, i need to use context for the sqlite database in broadcast receiver.

Comment: @shiva then it just context.getApplicationContext();